# JQuery dropdown selected not visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have bootstrap modal with 4 dropdownlists as below:
Client dropdown, 
Project dopdown, 
Task dropdown.

Task dropdown is dependent on project dropdown and project dropdown is depeded on client dropdown - when user selected client then he is able to select project and so after select project he is able to select task.

I have also fourth dropdown which containst  " Client / Project / Task " which values clientId/projectId/taskId.

Here is the function for fourth dropdown

```
  $("#mixedDropdown").change(function () {
        var value = $(this).val(); 
        var values = value.split("/"); // return [0]clientId [1]projectId [2]taskId
        $('#clientDropdown option[value="' + values[0] + '"]').attr("selected", "selected");
        clientDropdownOnChange(values[0], values[1], values[2]);
    });
```

The weird problem is that when user run the page for first time then everything works fine and after reopen modal and  user choose "mixed dropdowns" client is not being selected but still project propdown gets filled.

So the problem is that clientdropdown`s value is being changed but not not visible.

Comment: can u try to create a JSFiddle?

Comment: dropdowns are called with ajax

Comment: What values are you working with, do they really have a "/" in them. That seems sort of weird.

Comment: dropdown looks like option = " Client X / Project Y / Task Z " and as value= X/Y/Z" thats why I split value and I get each value needed